# CSS grid make items either span entire row or share space equally

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to build a grid that could, for example, look like this:

[image: example grid]

- Each item is manually given its `grid-row`, for example the item *D* has `grid-row: 6`
- If a row contains only one item, that item should span across the entire row, like the item *A*
- If a row contains multiple items, or in other words the items "overlap", they should share the row's space equally, like items *B* and *C* or *D*, *E* and *F*
- The `grid-column` property should NOT be given to items manually, for example I do not want to manually give the item *F* `grid-column: 5 / 7`. This is because **items will be inserted into the grid** one after the other, and when an item is inserted or removed the other items should adjust accordingly.

---

My current approach (that doesn't work) is this:

```css
    .grid {
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      display: grid;
      border: 1px solid red;
     }
     
     .item {
      border: 1px solid teal;
     }
     
     .item-a {
      grid-row: 1;
     }
     
     .item-b {
      grid-row: 2 / 4;
     }
     
     .item-c {
      grid-row: 3;
     }
```

```html
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="item item-a">a</div>
      <div class="item item-b">b</div>
      <div class="item item-c">c</div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, the item *a* does not span across the entire row. Giving every item `grid-column: span 2` just adds new columns and doesn't change the layout.

How can I achieve the desired grid?

Comment: CSS alone cannot do this

Comment: @TemaniAfif why not?